# CruiseControl: Does not start - how to determine reason?

Tags: jetty, startup, cruisecontrol, embedded-jetty

CruiseControl does not start any more (only known change was adding new memory to the machine.)

Ok, it seems to start: Calling the web gui brings:

```
HTTP ERROR: 404    
NOT_FOUND    
RequestURI=/    
Powered by jetty://
```

There are two exceptions in the log file:

```
2011-02-14 10:22:50.800::WARN:  FATAL@jar:file:/srv/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.2/lib/jsp-2.1.jar!/META-INF/fmt-1_0.tld line:1 col:14 : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: A pseudo attribute name is expected. 
2011-02-14 10:22:50.801::WARN:  EXCEPTION 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: A pseudo attribute name is expected. 
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanPseudoAttribute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLScanner.scanXMLDeclOrTextDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanXMLDeclOrTextDecl(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$XMLDeclDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:188)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:204)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.TagLibConfiguration.configureWebApp(TagLibConfiguration.java:227)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1217)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.web.EmbeddedJettyServer.start(EmbeddedJettyServer.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Main.startEmbeddedServer(Main.java:188)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Main.start(Main.java:131)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:259)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:117)
```

And:

```
2011-02-14 10:22:50.815::DEBUG: Container Server@1236cd5 + org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionIdManager@10c6cfc as sessionIdManager
2011-02-14 10:22:50.821::DEBUG: started org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionIdManager@10c6cfc
2011-02-14 10:22:50.821::DEBUG: started org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.HashSessionManager@1958bf9
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: filterNameMap={}
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: pathFilters=[]
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: servletFilterMap={}
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: servletPathMap={*.XSP=jsp, *.JSPX=jsp, *.jspf=jsp, *.jsp=jsp, *.jnlp=JnlpDownloadServlet, *.JSPF=jsp, *.jspx=jsp, /*=JnlpDownloadServlet, *.xsp=jsp, /=default, *.JSP=jsp}
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: servletNameMap={jsp=jsp, default=default, JnlpDownloadServlet=JnlpDownloadServlet}
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: starting ServletHandler@159e154
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: started ServletHandler@159e154
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: starting SecurityHandler@1be2893
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: started SecurityHandler@1be2893
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: starting SessionHandler@1d87b85
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: started SessionHandler@1d87b85
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: starting org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@1de45e2{/cc-config,file:/srv/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.2/webapps/cc-config/}
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: starting ErrorPageErrorHandler@118958e
2011-02-14 10:22:50.822::DEBUG: started ErrorPageErrorHandler@118958e
2011-02-14 10:22:50.994::DEBUG: loaded class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
2011-02-14 10:22:50.994::DEBUG: loaded class javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet from java.net.URLClassLoader@82c01f
2011-02-14 10:22:50.994::DEBUG: loaded class com.sun.javaws.servlet.JnlpDownloadServlet from ContextLoader@Cruisecontrol Webstart Client([file:/srv/cruisecontrol-bin-2.8.2/webapps/cc-config/WEB-INF/lib/jnlp-servlet.jar]) / java.net.URLClassLoader@82c01f
2011-02-14 10:22:50.994::DEBUG: Holding class com.sun.javaws.servlet.JnlpDownloadServlet
2011-02-14 10:22:50.995::DEBUG: started JnlpDownloadServlet
2011-02-14 10:22:50.995::DEBUG: loaded class org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet from java.net.URLClassLoader@82c01f
2011-02-14 10:22:50.995::DEBUG: Holding class org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2011-02-14 10:22:50.080::WARN:  failed jsp
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/JspFactory
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.init(JspServlet.java:134)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:433)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:616)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1220)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:513)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:448)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:222)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:39)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.web.EmbeddedJettyServer.start(EmbeddedJettyServer.java:105)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Main.startEmbeddedServer(Main.java:188)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Main.start(Main.java:131)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:259)
    at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:117)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspFactory
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:214)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:336)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: misplaced continuation line
    at java.util.jar.Attributes.read(Attributes.java:391)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Manifest.java:199)
    at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Manifest.java:69)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(JarFile.java:177)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(JarFile.java:163)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(URLClassPath.java:710)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:238)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    ... 28 more
```

Any ideas? What could have been changed? A file corrupted?